# How to search and retrieve values from multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, search, multidimensional-array

```
$array = [
            [
            "UF" => "Goias",
                    [
                    "Nome" => [
                            "Avenor",
                            "KENNEDY",
                            "JOSE"
                            ],
                    "Fone" => [
                            "+55 (91) 1111-1111",
                            "+55 (33) 2222-2222",
                            "+55 (93) 3333-3333"
                            ],
                    "Email" => [
                            "avenor@example.com",
                            "kennedy@example.com",
                            "sabino@example.com"
                            ]
                    ]
            ],
            [
            "UF" => "Amazonas",
                    [
                    "Nome" => [
                            "Kelsen",
                            "Joao",
                            "Kenia"
                            ],
                    "Fone" => [
                            "+55 (91) 4444-4444",
                            "+55 (33) 5555-5555",
                            "+55 (93) 6666-6666"
                            ],
                    "Email" => [
                            "kelsen@example.com",
                            "joao@example.com",
                            "kenia@example.com"
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
    ];
```

I want to create a list by searching this array and fill the list itens.
Ex.: When user select "Goias" I must search "Goias" through the array and return a list with "Nome", "Fone" and "Email" but I can't find a way to loop this array and return the correct values.

```
$selected = isset($_POST['selected']) ? $_POST['selected'] : 'nothing';
$key = array_search($selected,array_column($array, 'UF'));

foreach ($array[$key] as $data){

        echo '<li><p>Nome: '.$data["Nome"].'</p><p>Fone: '.$data["Fone"].'</p><p>E-mail: '.$data["Email"].'</p></li>';
};
```

EDIT:

I tried to do this:

```
 echo
         '<div class="representante-wrapper">
            <h3>'.$selected.'</h3>';
            foreach ($array[$key] as $data){
                    foreach($data as $value){
                    echo '<ul class="flex" id="dados" style="opacity: 1;">';
                    var_dump($value);
                            foreach($value["Nome"] as $nome){
                                    echo '<li><p>Nome: '.$nome.'</p></li>';
                            }
                            foreach($value["Fone"] as $fone){
                                    echo '<li><p>Fone: '.$fone.'</p></li>';
                            }
                            foreach($value["Email"] as $email){
                                    echo '<li><p>E-mail: '.$email.'</p></li>';
                            }
                    echo '</ul>';
                    }
            };
     echo '</div>';
```

but the result is not what I expect

```
Nome: Kelsen

Nome: Joao

Nome: Kenia

Fone: +55 (91) 4444-4444

Fone: +55 (33) 5555-5555

Fone: +55 (93) 6666-6666

E-mail: kelsen@example.com

E-mail: joao@example.com

E-mail: kenia@example.com
```

I want this as below, each array within your list:

```
Nome: Kelsen
Fone: +55 (91) 4444-4444
E-mail: kelsen@example.com


Nome: Joao
Fone: +55 (33) 5555-5555
E-mail: joao@example.com

Nome: Kenia
Fone: +55 (93) 6666-6666
E-mail: kenia@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search by key and value, something like:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // $key is "Goias"
    // $value is an array with "nome", "fone" and "Email" keys
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("UF" => array("Goias"=> array("Nome" =>   array("Avenor","KENNEDY","JOSE"),
                "Fone" => array("+55 (91) 1111-1111","+55 (33) 2222-2222","+55 (93) 3333-3333"),
                "Email" => array("avenor@example.com","kennedy@example.com","sabino@example.com")
                )
        ),
        array(
        "UF" => array("Amazonas"=>
                array(
                "Nome" => array(
                        "Kelsen",
                        "Joao",
                        "Kenia"
                        ),
                "Fone" => array(
                        "+55 (91) 4444-4444",
                        "+55 (33) 5555-5555",
                        "+55 (93) 6666-6666"
                        ),
                "Email" => array(
                        "kelsen@example.com",
                        "joao@example.com",
                        "kenia@example.com"
                        )
                )
        )
));
$selected = isset($_POST['selected']) ? $_POST['selected'] : 'nothing';
$i=0;
   foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if(isset($array[$i]['UF'][$selected])){
       break;
     }
   $i++;
  }
foreach ($array[$i]['UF'] as $data){
$li = '<li>';
foreach($data["Nome"] as $nome){
$li .= '<p>Nome:'.$nome.'</p>';
}
 foreach($data["Fone"] as $nome){
$li .= '<p>Fone:'.$nome.'</p>';
}
 foreach($data["Email"] as $nome){
$li .= '<p>E-mail:'.$nome.'</p>';
}
        $li .= '</li>';
echo $li;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't works, php returns:
"Undefined index: Nome";
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"